# Django models complex inheritance with proxys

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-inheritance

I have these models:

```
class Base(models.Model):
    # ... attributes
    def f(self):
        raise Exception()

class A(Base):
    attribute = models.IntegerField()

class B(A):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
    def f(self):
        print "B", attribute

class C(A):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
    def f(self):
        print "C", attribute
```

Now i play a bit with them, but i found a problem:

```
c = C()
c.attribute = 1
c.save()

b = Base.objects.all()
b.f() # Aspected "C 1" to be printed, exception fired instead!
```

The last line work in unexpected way! So looking to the documentation better, I searched for the Django automatic downcasting attribute, but i found only the one of the `A()` class that haven't automatic casting for neither `B()` or `C()`.

There's a way to save the inheritance also when i save the data?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation, a Queryset still returns the model that was requested. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#querysets-still-return-the-model-that-was-requested)

In your example you return a Queryset for the original model, Base.

Comment: Thanks, but there is anyway a method to recognize what kind of object is from and casting to it?